# Android ContentProvider generating data on-the-fly

Tags: android

In my app, I am exporting images with annotations. Because preparing all the images to be exported in advance would be too inefficient, I am rendering the images to be exported on the fly during the export. I do this with a custom ContentProvider for which the URI encodes the rendering parameters. The actual rendering is then done in ContentProvider.openFile(). This all works nicely.

However, I also have to provide results for the MediaStore MediaColumns in the query() method. But since the final image is not rendered yet, I do not know the SIZE of the data.

Searching for a solution, I came across this code:
http://code.google.com/p/openintents/source/browse/trunk/filemanager/FileManager/src/org/openintents/filemanager/FileManagerProvider.java?r=3267

which says in line 121 that for unknown sizes, we should return 'null' "according to the Android docs". But I cannot find this statement in any Android docs. Is this really the way to handle it? In fact, it works nicely with most apps I tried (e.g. GMail), but some simply show a zero file size (like AquaMail).

So, is returning 'null' for unknown file sizes in MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE the correct way to handle this?
And if yes, where is this documented?